# Restrict access to folder from a specific group

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

I have a directory named 'ballots' and a group named 'wheel'.
How do I restrict access from the group to the folder?

Comment: You mean you want (a) everybody in group wheel to not have access to the directory and (b) everybody not in group wheel to have access to the directory?

Comment: yes exactly, everybody else will have only write permissions.

Comment: As @Tango_Chaser said. Everybody have write permissions and the specific group has non